# Spark: Stateful stream processing by key

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have stream of data such as JSON records with an ID.

I would like to process the data such that all records with the same key are processed by the same stateful worker.

How can I do that?

Comment: For the answerer's information, is this data already deserialized into a proper data structure or does the answer also need to include loading your JSON into some kind of class? If it is already loaded into a class then spark, by default, already provides grouping and repartitioning methods.

Comment: Do you need the same data available across batches? Meaning not all data may arrive at the same batch?

Comment: can you explain the diffence?

Comment: How do you plan to handle failure on an executor?

Comment: Since [Spark 2.2.0](http://spark.apache.org/news/spark-2-2-0-released.html) was released you should seriously consider Structured Streaming to build a [stateful stream processing](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#arbitrary-stateful-operations) using Spark (as described also in [Faster Stateful Stream Processing in Apache Spark Streaming](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-apache-spark-streaming.html)).

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom Partition-er that will distribute data based on hash of Json id and same Id json will go to same partition and will be processed and each partition is going to get processed by same executor thread